# Finding an angle in a figure involving tangent circles

Tags: geometry, circles

The circle $A$ touches the circle $B$ internally at $P$. The centre $O$ of $B$ is outside $A$. Let $XY$ be a diameter of $B$ which is also tangent to $A$. Assume $PY > PX$. Let $PY$ intersect $A$ at $Z$. If $Y Z = 2PZ$, what is the magnitude of $\angle PYX$ in degrees?

What I have tried:

1. Obviously, the red angles are equal, and the orange angles are equal.  This gives $XY \parallel TZ$.
2. $YZ=2PZ$. From this $XY=3TZ$ then $O'Z=3OY$.  Let $O'Z=a=O'S$ so $SZ=\sqrt{2} a$, and also $O'O=2a$
3. Then $SO=\sqrt{3} a$. Now we can use trigonometry to find $\angle PYX$ in triangle $ZSY$.

[image: diagram]

Please verify whether my figure is correct.  Your solution to this question is welcomed, especially if it is shorter.

Comment: Why do we have $SO=3O'Z$? From $3TZ=XY$ it follows that $XO=3O'Z$, so we can't possible have $SO=3O'Z$...

Comment: Yah I have edited now

Comment: It's wrong again. Do check what you write before you ask other people.

Comment: Your solution looks more or less correct to me, but i have to concerns. 1. How do you find $ZY$ in terms of $a$? 2. How can you use trigonometry to determine$\angle PYX$

Comment: we can use power of point with Y i.e. $YS^2%=Yz*YP.

Comment: @math635 and by using cosine rule in triangle ZSY we can find it.

Comment: @Ayushakj And how do you find $PY$? I assume you want to solve this problem without looking up some table for trig functions, so unless the numbers turn out nicely it may be difficult to determine the angle with the cosine law...

Comment: @math635 we can PY in terms of ZY.Because in question(YZ=2PZ) and due to XY parallel to TZ, we have  two relation.  so YZ=(2/3)PZ   you are correct that without using trig. function table its difficult to calculate angle PYX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Triangle O'SO fits the description of a 30-60-90 special angled triangle. Therefore, $\angle O'OS = 30^0$

Then, $\angle PYX = 15^0$ [angles at center = 2 times angles at circumference]

Comment: Very nice...........+1 @ Mick

Comment: @Ayushakj The solution can be further simplified as follows. Prove that 1) O’Z // XY; 2) $\angle OSO’ = 90^0$; 3) $\triangle PZO’ \sim \triangle PYO$; 4) $OO’ : O’P = OO’ : O’S = 2 : 1$. With the last result and the facts that $OSO’$ is a right angled triangle with $OO’$ being its hypotenuse, you can conclude that $\angle SOO’ = 30^0$ already. In other words, there is no need to use point T.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Notice that $\angle PYX=\angle PYO= \angle OPY$ and $\angle POX=\angle PYO+\angle OPY$, so $$\angle PYX=\frac{1}{2}\angle POX$$
On the other hand,
$$\tan \angle POX=\frac{|O'S|}{|SO|}=\frac{a}{a\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\qquad\implies\qquad \angle POX=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=30^{\circ}$$